# Separate string into array of strings every n characters reverse and reversing back

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to format a large number, which is a String, into a locale's format. `toLocaleString()` or anything similar won't work, I have to do this manually. Forget replacing a `.` with a `,` for the moment, I just want to separate the number into chunks of 3 (like chunks of thousands). I'm trying to do this by reversing the String, splitting it into an array every 3 characters, and reversing back.

```
const chunkByThree = (input) => {
  let chunkedInput = input.split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,3}/g);
  chunkedInput = chunkedInput.reverse();

  return chunkedInput;
}
```

However, let's take a large number, like `'1243525152519'`. It should be separated into
`['1', '243', '525', '152', '519']` but because `reverse()` only affects the order of the array's elements and not the values themselves, the function will return `[ '1', '342', '525', '251', '915' ]` when reversing it back (line 3). How can I correctly reverse it back, by also reversing the strings inside each array value aside from the order of the array's elements?

Comment: Why do you "have to do this manually"? Why not use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)?

Comment: @rayhatfield Intl.NumberFormat will be unreliable with large decimals, as it will start rounding up after very large numbers (even if I use max/minFractionDecimals options). The numbers need to be exact. They also come as Strings from my API.

Comment: You can use map, then split reverse and join. But why reverse the string in the first place ?

Comment: how should the string look at the end, with dot and commas?

Comment: If I understood correctly what you want, you can entirely avoid the entire split/reverse/join process; I posted an alternative solution showing how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consume the digits from an array using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), lopping off 3 from the end on each iteration. If there are fewer than 3 digits left you'll get whatever remains (the remaining 1 or 2 digits).

(Using [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) allows you to keep the chunks in the correct order by pushing into the start of the array instead of appending to the end.)

Then you can reassemble the chunks with join. No regex or reversing required.

Something like this?

```js
const num = '1243525152519';
const digits = num.split('');
const chunks = [];

while(digits.length) { // as long as we have more digits…
  // …lop off the last three and stringify them,
  // push it into the start of the chunks array:
  chunks.unshift(digits.splice(-3).join(''));
}

// then reassemble the chunks with your preferred delimiter
const result = chunks.join(',') // join the chunks
console.log(result); // voila
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split each chunk again using map and then reverse them and then join them again.

You can so something like this:

```js
const chunkByThree = (input) => {
  let chunkedInput = input
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .join("")
    .match(/.{1,3}/g)
    .reverse()
    .map((i) => i.split("").reverse().join(""));

  return chunkedInput;
};

console.log(chunkByThree("1243525152519"));
```

---

#### The process (in the map)

1. It will take the `i` element of the array. Example: `"342"`.
2. Split the `i` element, Like this: `["3", "4", "2"]`.
3. Then it will reverse this arr, Like this: `["2", "4", "3"]`.
4. Now it will join all the elements of the array, Like this: `"243"`.
5. At last it will return the string (`"243"`).

```
. 
.
.
.map((i) => i.split("").reverse().join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could do:

```js
function splitNumericString(str) {
  const firstChunkLength = str.length % 3;
  let output = [];

  if (firstChunkLength > 0) {
    output.push(str.slice(0, firstChunkLength));
  }
  
  output.push(...str.slice(firstChunkLength).match(/.{3}/g))

  return output
}

// test
const str = '1243525152519';
console.log(splitNumericString(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ***ray hatfield*** already provided the most straightforward approach of [splicing 3-digit junks from the right and unshifting them (stacking from left)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66804083/separate-string-into-array-of-strings-every-n-characters-reverse-and-reversing-b/66804250#66804250), I was curious about how a similar but regex-based approach might look like.

It actually turned out to be simpler than initially thought. The base it a regex ... [`/(?<!\b)(\d{3}\b)/`](https://regex101.com/r/FLADiS/1) ... which features a negative lookbehind and matches exactly a single possible right most thousand (digit-)group at a time. As long as it matches one does `replace` its captured group with itself and a prefixed dot ...

```js
function formatThousands(str, separator) {
  separator = (typeof separator === 'string') && separator || ',';
  str = String(str);

  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/FLADiS/1]
  const regXrightMostThousandGroup = (/(?<!\b)(\d{3}\b)/);
  const template = `${ separator }$1`;

  while (regXrightMostThousandGroup.test(str)) {
    str = str.replace(regXrightMostThousandGroup, template);
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(formatThousands('1243525152519', ','));
console.log(formatThousands('21243525152519', '.'));
console.log(formatThousands('321243525152519', ' '));
console.log(formatThousands('9321243525152519'));
console.log(formatThousands('19321243525152519', '.'));
console.log(formatThousands('419321243525152519', ' '));
console.log(formatThousands('7419321243525152519'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```